# Vue computed property not updating as expected

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I have a count

```
  You have {{ keywordsLeft }} keywords left
```

and in my Vue.

```
var u = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        keywords:keywords,
        user:user,
        total_keywords:user.total_keywords,
    },
    computed: {
        keywordsLeft: function () {
           var left = total_keywords-keywords.length;
           if(left<=0){
             return 0;
           } else {
             return left;
           }
       }
   }, 
   methods: {
       deleteKeyword: function(keyword){
           var i = this.keywords.indexOf(keyword);
           this.keywords.splice(i,1);
       }
   }
       // rest of VUE code.
```

Whenever an update is made to the data, the computed value doesnt update.  I have to refresh the page to do it.  I thought the purpose of computed property was live reactivity?  Am I missing something?

Do I need to explicitly update it somehow? recompute is manually? Forgive me if Im being stupid, but this seems like a waste if its not done automatically.  Might as well just use jquery then lol

Comment: How about `keywordsLeft: () => Math.max(0, total_keywords - keywords.length)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computed properties are computed automatically and they're what you're supposed to use in a case like this.

I guess the problem lies somewhere in the code that updates your actual data. It is doing it in a way that doesn't work with Vue's reactivity system. This happens to many people :)

I suggest you to read this for overall guide https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html and this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection for gotchas on arrays.

Added:

I see your problem now. Inside the keywordsLeft computed property you're not referring to the Vue instance's data but actually to the original data. What I mean the keywords.length refers to the original keywords object and its length. Same with total_keywords - it doesn't refer to the Vue instance's data. You should use ***this.keywords*** and ***this.total_keywords***.

I always keep the instance data property names different from the outside/global/not-Vue data. I'm saying something like this is better:

```
data: {
  myKeywords: keywords,
  myTotalKeywords: totalKeywords
  ...
}
```

This way you cannot mix what you're referring to. Now you should refer to this.myKeywords etc. inside the Vue instance's scope.

Comment: when Im deleting a keyword Im using....     this.keywords.splice(i,1); The view updates fine, and the keyword is removed, but the count doesnt update.  Is there another way I should be removing items from a data object to force the count update??  I remember reading somewhere that I had to do Vue.set().  But I tried that and nothing changed, so just resorted to using a method instead.  So Im not really sure how to use computed properties now.

Comment: Sounds pretty much correct. Please update your question with the code that handles the update! It's a lot easier to guide you when the code is available :)

Comment: I added the delete.  Its pretty mich exactly as I stated in the comment.  Don't really see anything glaringly wrong with it.....I mean....the view updates fine.  And it gets deleted.  So its working.  Just the compute, doesnt recompute.  But if I put it into a method, then it works.

Comment: also adding this.$forceUpdate(); after the splice, doesnt make the compute, re-compute either

Comment: @KyleK check out the added section in my anwer.

Comment: Ah yes.  That was it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

K I solved it by just moving it into a method.  Even though I feel this is wrong, it works.  Not really sure the purpose of computed properties now.  Since they seem to only compute once?

Anyway heres how I fixed it.

The HTML

```
You have {{ keywordsLeft() }} keywords left
```

The Vue

```
var u = new Vue({
el:'#app',
data:{
    keywords:keywords,
    user:user,
    total_keywords:user.total_keywords,
},
methods: {
    keywordsLeft: function () {
       var left = total_keywords-keywords.length;
       if(left<=0){
         return 0;
       } else {
         return left;
       }
   }
},
```

Super simple.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened frequently for me.

To solve that, I tried to add `key` as that computed value and it worked perfectly.

```
 <span :key="keywordsLeft">
    You have {{ keywordsLeft() }} keywords left
 </span>
...
 computed: {
        keywordsLeft: function () {
           var left = total_keywords-keywords.length;
           if(left<=0){
             return 0;
           } else {
             return left;
           }
       }
   },
```

When key is changed, that component(dom) will be re-rendered.